# Casting NIO Channel at Run Time

Tags: java, android, nio

I have a class that implements 'Runnable' to read data from a data stream. The data comes from a `Channel` which is stored as a member variable in another of my classes, and I can get an instance of this channel by simply calling the getter `getInputChannel()`. Now, for my `Runnable` to read the data from the channel, it needs to know what type of channel it is so that it can use the channel's `read` method. The channel type may be one of either `FileChannel` or `SocketChannel`, and is decided at run time, i.e.,

```
private class ReadInputStream implements Runnable {

    Thread thread;
    boolean running = true;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    FileChannel or SocketChannel channel;

    public ReadInputStream() {
        // Need to cast type channel at run time
        Channel ch = getInputChannel();
        this.channel = (FileChannel or SocketChannel) ch;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
             channel.read(buffer);
             // etc.
        }
    }
```

}

What is the best way to get the right type of channel so that I can implement its `read` method in the runnable's `run()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both FileChannel and SocketChannel implement [ByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ByteChannel.html) which is what declares their `read(ByteBuffer)` method, so that's the type your `getInputChannel()` should return.

**Edit** Or if you only ever read from the channel, return a [ReadableByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) as Darkhogg says.  Since this is an input channel, this is most likely the case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Java to express union types. Your best bet is to use some common interface that applies to both.

If you're using the channel only for reading, define it to be a `ReadableByteChannel`.
If you're using it for writing, use a `WritableByteChannel`.
If you need *both*, use `ByteChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple if/else clause and cycle through the available instance types, for instance (no pun intended..):

```
if (channel instanceof FileChannel)
    {
         ((FileChannel)channel).read(buffer);
    }
    else if (channel instanceof SocketChannel)
    {
        ((SocketChannel)channel).read(buffer);
    }
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Fallso. I considered this, but not ideal as it brings extra logic into the `run` method.

Comment: That's OK! I'd go with Darkhogg/JeremyP's suggestion, I didn't see that they both implement ByteChannel, but that's a nice easy change.